# How can I create an infinite loop for entering names in a string list?

Tags: c#, list, loops, foreach

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Add a new Name:");
            List<string> namensLists = new List<string>();
            
            
            *Code ?
```

// I tried with the do-while loop, got an infinite loop on the one hand, but couldn't jump out of it to output it in the Foreach loop afterwards.*

```
            foreach (var name in namensLists)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{name}");
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

Comment: Your post doesn't include the most relevant part of the question, the loop that you apparently wrote to do what you're asking about.

Comment: You can do `while (true) { }` but you have to have some sentinel word (ex: "", or "q" or "quit") that the user enters to let you know when to `break`.

Comment: Your `do-while` loop sounds like the way to go. You just need to add some condition (perhaps like the user typing "end" as a name) that causes a `break` of the loop. What would that condition be?

Comment: Side note: `Console.WriteLine($"{name}");` can just be `Console.WriteLine(name);`

Comment: "but couldn't jump out of it" Well, why not? Do you know how to "jump out" of a `while` loop *in general*? If not, then that's the actual question, not how to create the loop - and this is a question that is answered by following a C# tutorial and learning the fundamentals. If you *do* know, then you are asking for *debugging help*. In this case, please keep in mind: a) we can only help you with code that you actually show to us; b) you are [expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) to [try](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for yourself first.

Answer (score 1):

When entering names in an *inifinte* loop, you should have some *escape*; let's stop entering names on *empty* input:

```
List<string> namensLists = new List<string>();

// infinite loop ...
while (true) {
  Console.Write("Add a new Name (empty one to stop): ");
  
  string input = Console.ReadLine();

  // ... which we break on escape input (here on empty input)
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
    break;
  
  namensLists.Add(input); 
}
```

Comment: thx. Sometimes I think far too complicatedly.

Comment: I have modified it a little. But that's how I wanted it to be spent.
It just didn't occur to me. Thank you.